# Rails 3 joining a related model with it's default scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I'm trying to query across models with the following setup

```
Class Scorecard < AR::Base
  default_scope where(:archived => false)
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :scorecard_metrics
end

Class ScorecardMetric < AR::Base
  belongs_to :scorecard
end

Class User < AR::Base
  has_many :scorecards
end
```

I am trying to query from scorecard metrics with a named scope that joins scorecard and I want it to include the default scope for scorecard, my current implementation (which works) looks like this

```
# on ScorecardMetric
scope :for_user, lambda { 
  |user| joins(:scorecard).
         where("scorecards.user_id = ? and scorecards.archived = ?", user.id, false) 
}
```

This just seems messy to me, is there any way to join and include the default scope of the joined association?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I found the answer I was looking for, I just did this

```
scope :for_user, lambda { |user| joins(:scorecard).where('scorecards.user_id = ?', user.id) & Scorecard.scoped }
```

which is much nicer without the duplicated logic

Comment: what does `& Scorecard.scoped` mean?

Comment: Scorecard.scoped is just the default scope for Scorecards and the & performs a union